# Removing some characters from string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I'm using the following regex:

```
documentText = Regex.Replace(documentText, "\\\\|\\^|\\+|\\*|~|#|=|\"", "");
```

and it works. But when I split this string by using:

```
wordsInText = documentText.ToLower().Split(' ').ToList();
```

I get elements that are marked as `""` (empty string). I can remove it manually by iterating through collection and removing empty elements, but it must be a way to prevent this weird behaviour.

Comment: You mean, the original `documentText` didn't contain consecutive blanks but after replacing it does? Then just use the regex string `"(\\\\|\\^|\\+|\\*|~|#|=|\") ?"` instead

Comment: Independently of your question, I suggest that for your regex you use a verbatim string for readability: `@"\\|\^|\+|\*|~|#|=|"""`

Comment: Bergi, you're right. I tried to use your regex pattern but it still leaves blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
documentText.ToLower().Split(new char[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you use a `char` array if it is only one delimiter character?

Comment: @m.buettner Because there is no overloaded method that takes a char and StringSplitOptions

Comment: Thanks L.B. This works, but is it possible to solve this issue inside regex.